# How to get the primary key (e.g. ID) of just inserted to SQLITE DB in most efficient way?

Tags: sql, sqlite

for instance:
a table created as below:

```
create table tbl_text( id integer primary key, txt text unique, ref integer );
```

insert a record:

```
insert into tbl_text values(null, "Hello", 123);
```

how to get the id of "Hello" just inserted in fastest way? 
query works but it might be time-consuming, e.g.

```
select id from tbl_text where txt='Hello'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `last_insert_rowid()` or `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` depending on how you're accessing sqlite. Watch out for another thread running an insert on the same connection, more about that in their [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html), from the docs it *returns the rowid of the most recent successful INSERT into the database from the database connection*.